# Liquibase , how to add a group of fields like primary key?

Tags: spring, liquibase

I have an entity with a group of fields in primary key.
Like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pv_object")
@NamedQuery(name = "PreviousObject.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM PreviousObject p")
public class PreviousObject implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FieldsDTO fieldsdto; 

    //
}
```

FieldsDTO class contains 2 String and 2 Integer.

I have and I use Liquidbase on my project in a XML file, but, I don't know how to represent this ID of 4 fields in liquidbase.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `<addPrimaryKey` you can configure `columnNames` by all your columns that compose your primary key

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="addPrimaryKey-example">
    <addPrimaryKey
        columnNames="id, name"
        constraintName="pk_person"
        schemaName="public"
        tableName="person"
        tablespace="A String"/>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 15):

Assign the same `primaryKeyName` to them.

```
    <createTable tableName="pv_object">
        <column name="x" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_pv_object"/>
        </column>
        <column name="y" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_pv_object"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `nullabe="false"` be implied and default for a primary key?

Comment: It does not work for me, it is posible since some specific version?

Comment: I was able to create a composite PK by just setting `primaryKey="true"` without the name

Answer (score 1):

or add separately

```
<addPrimaryKey tableName="REPRESENTATIVE" columnNames="REPRESENTED_USER_ID,REPRESENTATIVE_ID"
                constraintName="REPRESENTED_REPRESENTATIVE_PK" />
```